# GitHub Action Js: importing modules from a different project in a github action

Tags: reactjs, yaml, github-actions

I am trying to figure out whether it's possible for me to import files from a different project folder. Due to certain constraints, these folders need to be separated, and I am not allowed to put one project folder into the other...

An example:

```
Project1
   ├── moduleA.test.js

Project2
   ├── moduleB.js
```

*In Project1/moduleA.test.js*

```js
//This works locally but not on GitHub Action because the project folder is only available locally
import { moduleB } from '../Project2/moduleB';
...
```

I tried checking out Project2 thinking that it would allow the importing to work but it didn't for me.

*In Project1/.github/workflows/pr.yml*

```yaml
    - name: Checkout Project2
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
      with:
        repository: my-org/Project2
        token: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}
        path: my-tools
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You probably wanna look at the absolute path of where these actions are checked out. This is going to be quite a brittle setup though.. If there's no possibility for one folder to be inside the other, would it be possible to create a separate action/repository that combines both of them at build time?